# Ubuntu does not login after resizing partitions with GParted

Tags: partitioning, logging

I recently needed to enlarge the windows 7 partition on my laptop and shrinked with GParted the one in which I have Ubunt. The problem is that now, after logging in, my desktop does not activate and I nothing except the mouse pointer.

Nevertheless my data are still there, this I checked by logging in after doing CTRL+ALT+F1

Is there a way in which I could just backup and reinstall everything without loosing my previous data?

Bests!

Comment: Did you shrink the ubuntu partition as small as possible?  If you did then there likely is insufficient free space left.  I personally recommend that at least 10% unused space is left in a partition when shrinking.

Answer (score 0):

Before reinstalling our system you could try to reinstall the window-manager.

For a default install

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

If this doesn't work or you don't want to try what else might be broken, save your data to an external drive by using tty with [cp](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cp) and maybe [mount](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mount)